# Why is PUT request body undefined?

Tags: node.js, put, koa

I'm making the following request to my koajs server:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : 'PUT',        // this.request.body undefined server side
    // type         : 'POST',   // this.request.body all good server side
    url         : url,
    data        : body,
    dataType    : 'json'
})
```

But on the server side `this.request.body` is always undefined.

If I change the request type to POST, it works fine.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

I'm using `koa-route`.

---

**EDIT 2**

Just realised I'm using `koa-body-parser`, which is probably more relevant.

Comment: What middleware are you using to parse the request body?

Comment: I'm using `koa-route`, which seems to be automatically parsing the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the koa-body parser:

```
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
app.use(bodyParser())
```

I think koa-router will parse typical request stuff, url params, forms etc.  If you want to parse the body of a request that contains a JSON object you need to apply a middleware (as alex alluded to).

Also please check to see if you are putting valid JSON.

Take a look at this Koa-bodyparser:

```
/**
 * @param [Object] opts
 *   - {String} jsonLimit default '1mb'
 *   - {String} formLimit default '56kb'
 *   - {string} encoding default 'utf-8'
 */

  return function *bodyParser(next) {
    if (this.request.body !== undefined) {
      return yield* next;
    }

    if (this.is('json')) {
      this.request.body = yield parse.json(this, jsonOpts);
    } else if (this.is('urlencoded')) {
      this.request.body = yield parse.form(this, formOpts);
    } else {
      this.request.body = null;
    }

    yield* next;
  };
```

there looks to be a 1mb limit on the amount of JSON.  then to co-body/lib/json.js

```
module.exports = function(req, opts){
  req = req.req || req;
  opts = opts || {};

  // defaults
  var len = req.headers['content-length'];
  if (len) opts.length = ~~len;
  opts.encoding = opts.encoding || 'utf8';
  opts.limit = opts.limit || '1mb';

  return function(done){
    raw(req, opts, function(err, str){
      if (err) return done(err);

      try {
        done(null, JSON.parse(str));
      } catch (err) {
        err.status = 400;
        err.body = str;
        done(err);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Cheers for the response!  Um, I just realised I'm already using `koa-body-parser`...  Any idea why it's parsing the request body for POST and not PUT?

Comment: Um no - you may need to dig into the source code.  THe koa stuff is pretty new.

Comment: Hm, I don't think the JSON is the problem, because it works fine for the POST request.

Comment: The same for the 1mb limit, if that was the problem the POST should also not have a body.

Comment: Appreciate all the help akaphenom!  I'll just stick with the POST request for now.

Comment: I ended up trying `koa-bodyparser` like you suggested instead of `koa-body-parser`, and it worked first try!  Cheers akaphenom